# How to access Controller Class from Express 4 Middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a project using ExpressJS v4.

I have the following structure in order of execution.

1. Register Middlewares
2. Register Handlers (handlers are ES6 classes's methods)

So, my handlers look like ..

```
let aCtrl = new AController(...);
let bCtrl = new BController(...);

let blogCtrl = new BlogController(...);

app.get('/blog/post/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    return blogCtrl.showBlogPost(req, res, next);
});

...
```

What I am doing in the authentication middleware is :

```
    userCheckMiddlware(req, res, next)
    {
       if(authSuccess) 
            next();
        else 
            res.sendStatus(401);
    }
```

Now, what I want to do is something in the lines of

```
    userCheckMiddlware(req, res, next)
    {
        if(controller.doesNotRequireAuth) {
            next();
        }

        if(authSuccess) 
            next();
        else 
            res.sendStatus(401);
    }
```

Now, my problem is how do I get the handler i.e Controller object that has the `doesNotRequireAuth()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Well you cant. It is middleware that is hit before the controller is even known.

But you do not have to put this into controller itself, you can choose if you use it as middleware or not.

i.e.

```
// bearerAuth is middleware method for authentize
router.get('/users/me', bearerAuth, user.me);
router.put('/users/me', bearerAuth, user.me);
router.patch('/users/me', bearerAuth, user.me);
router.delete('/users/me', bearerAuth, user.me);
router.post('/images', image.upload); //You can upload images without auth
```

Comment: I thought Express would parse the request and decide the handler first and then start the execution of the middle-wares. Is it not so ?

Comment: Yes, it iterates through handlers and looks for URL match. If it matches, express executes middlewares one by one. But it does not know, the "last middleware" (which is usually controller) before it is executed.